# C# FileSystemWatcher file size is only updating with windows explorer

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, windows-explorer

I've a problem with the FileSystemWatcher in C#.
I watch a file used by another program.
This is not a problem. The problem is that the only value that changes with the file is the size. The other program is writing the file without updating the change or write date.
And the size value is only updating when the (windows 7) explorer refreshing (F5, or clicked on the file).

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileWatcher_Changed);
fileWatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path); // get directory of file path.
fileWatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(path); // only this file
fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilter.Size; // and maybe other
fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

private void fileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

I guess that this problem can only be solved by polling. Because the file should be triggered for refreshing file info data. 
But I hope for another solution without polling.

About my application: 
Reading a file which is in use of another program. Getting the text of the file is possible with FileStream FileShare.ReadWrite. It's working fine. I want to update the textbox (reading the file) when the file has been changed. But the only value who is updating while the other program is accessing to it, is the file size. But only when the explorer is refreshing or I'm clicking on the file. This is the issue of this question. If the problem is unsolvable, the alternative is: updating the file content (reading file) all x time. (polling) without a file watcher.

Comment: "And the size value is only updating when the (windows 7) explorer refreshing (F5, or clicked on the file)." -- Are you saying the `fileWatcher.Changed` event only fires when you refresh an already-open Windows Explorer window that is open to the directory containing the file?

Comment: Yes, only when the windows explorer is open and refreshing by F5 or clicking on the file. I think, the FileSystemWatcher is only checking the prev. and actual values. And by default, the size value is not updating by itself. Perhaps it needs to much ressources of the system. But only when the explorer is using to open the directory, or refresh by F5 or clicking on the file. But the size is changing, I see it in the file properties.

Comment: I see the size in windows explorer and I am sure that the other programm is wrting it. I have no FileInfo object. My application is for reading this file on change (size changed, because change date is not updating). It's possible with FileStream FileShare.ReadWrite. This makes it possible to read a file which is used by another program. The ONLY problem, is that the size information (the only value who is updating in explorer) is not updating without the windows explorer. It looks like I have to cyclically trigger. But I do not want anything cyclic (polling), just on file change event.

Comment: No, my application does nothing, just listening on the file watcher. Another program is writing to the file continuously as stream. The only value who is updating when I check the file in explorer is the size in bytes. My application is just printing out a text, when the change events is fired. And I see that the event is only ticking when I clicking on the file or pressing F5 in the explorer. The explorer is triggering the event indirectly because the size value of the byte is only changing when the explorer is updating it.

Comment: Sorry about the comment spam, I replied before reading your fully edited first reply. I deleted the extra comments. The important information is here: "My application is just printing out a text, when the change events is fired. And I see that the event is only ticking when I clicking on the file or pressing F5 in the explorer"; that is not how I would expect it to work. Now that the question is clarified maybe someone knows of some caveats with the FileSystemWatcher and why it's behaving this way.

Comment: Right, why does the size value not updating itself? in my opinion the file watcher is not really a file watcher when he needs a external trigger. It's more an observer, just comparing existing values. Btw. if the file is closing by the other program, the change event is also throwing, because the system updates the change date. But the size date is a special case. I'm afraid that this problem is unsolvable. Perhaps, only when triggering the file by my application. But if this is true, I can do the job without the FileWatcher. Only by polling the file content at a time cycle. *sigh*

Comment: Where is the file located? According to my experience FileWatcher works perfect on local drives but so-so on network shares. And idea: instead of pooling content pool file size in some intervals to trigger reading file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, following would solve your problem, and avoid polling. Try using **WMI**, querying **root\cimv2** namespace with something like:

`select filesize from 'cim_datafile' where name='_your_path_'`

Might differ slightly when applied from C# but along those lines. Regarding WMI, there's lots of tutorials how to initialize a WMI listener in .NET. Search around.